# Filter display events

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I tried to use the new event hooks from fullcalendar v5 but I'm having a problem.

```
eventContent: function (obj) {
                let current_id = obj.event.extendedProps._id;
                if ($.inArray(current_id, filtered_ids)) {
                    obj.event.setProp('display', 'none');
                }
            }
```

What it should return? I tried with obj, obj.event but none works. It expects according to docs text or html. Can obj.event be rendered?

Thanks

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection explains it I think. You must return either unescaped text, or HTML wrapped in an object, or an array of DOM nodes wrapped in an object. There are examples shown on that page of each of those.

Comment: But anyway, `obj.event.setProp('display', 'none');` makes no sense in this context - `event is an [event object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object), and you're in "eventContent" you're about to render a HTML element. It's too later to set the event's properties and expect fullCalendar to notice them - it has already rendered the HTML element, it's just giving you a last-minute chance to amend that contents within that element. And if you want to hide the element, you can't do it in eventContent anyhow, because you can only affect what's inside it, not the overall element itself.

Comment: It looks like you might be able to achieve your goal via `eventDidMount` which, according to the docs, gives you access to an extra `el` property representing the final rendered element - so you could set it hidden then.

Comment: Thank you all. In the meanwhile I have solved it by taking all events, parsing them and modify their display property in a loop according to filters.